# POSTFIX Error: 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO)

Tags: linux, postfix, g-suite, opensuse

I setting `main.cf` in postfix on Linux SUSE like this

```
inet_interfaces = localhost
inet_protocols = ipv4

masquerade_domains =
masquerade_exceptions = root
mydestination = $myhostname, localhost.$mydomain
myhostname = localhost
mynetworks_style = subnet
relayhost=[smtp-relay.gmail.com]:25

smtpd_delay_reject = yes
smtpd_helo_required = no

smtpd_client_restrictions =

smtpd_helo_restrictions =

smtp_sasl_auth_enable = no
smtp_sasl_security_options =
smtp_sasl_password_maps =
smtpd_sasl_auth_enable = no

smtp_use_tls = no
```

I tried to `telnet smtp-relay.gmail.com 25` and it's working

Anyway, when I tried to send email with postfix in server I got the issue.

```
root@localhost
(host smtp-relay.gmail.com[ipv4] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at the [official Google documentation](https://support.google.com/a/answer/3726730?hl=en) looks like a "ratelimit" on their side:

```
 421, "4.7.0", Try again later, closing connection. This usually indicates a Denial of Service (DoS) for the SMTP relay at the HELO stage.
```

How many mails per minute are you sending? By experience, usually Gmail accepts 50/100 mail/minute tops.

**EDIT as per comment**

Well, looks like the same error appears with a wrong HELO/HELO (as I first suspected).

I just tried:

```
$> telnet smtp-relay.gmail.com 25
Trying 108.177.15.28...
Connected to gmail-smtp-relay.l.google.com.
Escape character is '^]'.
220 smtp-relay.gmail.com ESMTP b8-v6sm74445wrr.1 - gsmtp
helo localhost
421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO) b8-v6sm74445wrr.1 - gsmtp
Connection closed by foreign host.
```

So it's definitively your EHLO string.

You have `myhostname = localhost` in your `main.cf` file, you should change it with `myhostname = [your server fqdn]`, i.e. you should have a [Fully qualified domain name](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fully_qualified_domain_name) for your server, complete with correct DNS/rDNS entries.

Comment: I just sent only 1 email per minute or I can say 1 email per hour.

Comment: Using temporary error code on a permanent error is not very wise from Google.

Comment: @Mr Shunz, I still don't have FQDN just now maybe the process will finish on the next week, so can I use ip adress instead?

Comment: @user9111600 I just tried and it seems the error does not appear when using `helo IP.ADD.RE.SS`. Give it a try!

Comment: @ Mr Shunz, I just try with your suggestion but it still showing..  root@localhost
(delivery temporarily suspended: host smtp-relay.gmail.com[74.125.24.28] refused to talk to me: 421 4.7.0 Try again later, closing connection. (EHLO)

Comment: It showing error already: postfix: warning: valid_hostname: numeric hostname: 110.49.142.77

maybe I cannot use ip to being hostname.

Comment: @user9111600 you should definitively get a FQDN then.

Answer (score 2):

I did run into this issue when using the Symfony/Mailer in my PHP Application. Which did use the SMTP relay like this:

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://smtp-relay.gmail.com:587
```

The fix was defining the `local_domain` parameter:

```
MAILER_DSN=smtp://smtp-relay.gmail.com:587?local_domain=your-domain.com
```

Comment: This solution worked for me!